# How can I access the file-link.html.twig template?

Tags: views, files

I'm trying to access the functionality of the file-link.html.twig template that comes with the classy theme so that I can have the file-type icons automatically appear next to the file links.

[image]

I've tried using the `file_url` and `link` functions in twig, but with no success.

Here's an example of what my file_url looks like `{{ file_url(node.field_agenda_files_upload.entity.uri.value) }}`

This just outputs something like `/sites/default/files/2020-07/file.pdf`

I'm new to Drupal, so please be kind.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean by "access the functionality of" some template file? Are you trying to change what Classy does? Are you implementing a different template altogether but trying to show these icons?

Comment: Sorry yes, I have created a new page template. If I output the contents of `page.content`, the files show up with the icons. However, if I'm trying to figure out how to get the same functionality when using `file_url(node.field_agenda_files_upload.entity.uri.value) }}`

Comment: Rendering an icon is no "functionality", this is a template. Write HTML code

Comment: @Hudri see `template_preprocess_file_link()` in `file.module`.

Comment: @bigmike7801 `file_url()` only prints the URL of the file. `file_link()`, as you mentioned, prints the link, but I don't think it's accessible in TWIG files by default. Have you considered creating a view?

Comment: You might find what you are looking for in the [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. It has a `{{ drupal_field(...) }}` operator, which renders a complete field template. See [cheat sheet](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#drupal-field)